# Modify the results in "Find and Replace" dialog for Excel 2003

Tags: excel, excel-2003

My end goal is for "Find and Replace" to take an extra parameter and to show me a custom column in the "Results" table when I click "Find All".

When I search a spreadsheet for "value" and click "Find All", the dialog shows me the Book, Sheet, Name, Cell, Value, Formula for every cell that has "value" in it.  But I want it to show me the contents of another cell in that row as well.  I would like that cell to be from a column I specify when I enter the seach parameters.

I'm relatively new to programming, and am sure that I can figure out something with Python or AutoHotKey.  But I would be surprised if there isn't a better way.

I don't want something that is associated with the spreadsheet or workbook specifically, so it needs to be part of Excel or stand alone (not a macro from what I understand).  Is it possible to modify the Find and Replace dialog box in Excel?

A point in the right direction would be much appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible (at least with any sensible level of effort) to modify the built-in search functionality to add parameters and to display different output. You would need to create a similar tool in your language of choice and build in your new requirements.